# EF SqlQuery Parameter error

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

Using

```
string sql = @"
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM Log 
ORDER BY Date desc";
return context.Database.SqlQuery<Log>(sql).ToList();
```

work, but when i'm trying to insert parameter like

```
string sql = @"
SELECT TOP @top *
FROM Log 
ORDER BY @order";

List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("top", top)); //top is int with value 50
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("order", order)); //order is string with value Date desc

return context.Database.SqlQuery<Log>(sql, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```

I get

> "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@top'.".

Where I wrong?

Comment: write like this : `SELECT TOP (@top)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange your query as following

```
string sql = @"
SELECT TOP (@top) *
FROM Log 
ORDER BY @order";
```

**EDIT**

```
string sql = @"
SELECT TOP @top *
FROM Log 
ORDER BY ";

sql += order;

List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("top", top)); //top is int with value 50

return context.Database.SqlQuery<Log>(sql, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's solved the top parameter. Now i get "Additional information: The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name." Whats that?

Comment: aren't you using column name as `@order` value?

Comment: Column name is "Date" (log4net) and @order string value is "Date desc"

Comment: You can't use a parameter to indicate a column. This is true for basic SQL and probably true also for EF

Comment: please see my edited answer. It will solve your problem

Comment: thanks! its more correct use += or {0} string format?

Comment: No absolutely no. string.Format is no more secure than string concatenation. You should not leave this hole in your application if you use that string to build sql queries. The only exception is if you have strict control on the input but still ,,,,

Comment: Yes! Thanks @gypsyCode all problems are fixed now

Comment: @Sauren So, you can mark it as the answer of your question